# synchronized blocks android

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronized

I have one function: `fillFromDB` which fills an instances of `ArrayList` called `list` from the SQLite DB.

I also have another `Thread` which is suppose to clear that `list` and re-populate it.

I'm having some issues with the list, since sometimes the other `Thread` clear the list while the first one is still filling it,  causing `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on an Adapter.

```
// This occurs onCreate()
fillFromDb(list);
downloadAndRepopulateList(list);


private void downloadAndRepopulateList(List list) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            list.clear();
            // Some other clode
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the issue is cause they are not Thread-safe, but I have never used `synchronized` before.

So my question is:

if I change the download function like this:

```
private void downloadAndRepopulateList(List list) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {

            synchronized(list) {

                list.clear();
                // Some other clode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will it wait for the UIThread to finish filling the list on `fillFromDb()` and then proceed to clear and repopulate it?

if not, how should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though I would rather recommend using `LinkedBlockingQueue`. i.e.

```
  list = new LinkedBlockingQueue<SomeType>();
  fillFromDb(list);
  downloadAndRepopulateList(list);

private void downloadAndRepopulateList(List list) {
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
         list.clear();
        // Some other clode
    }
}
}
```

[LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) will itself manage synchronization for you and you dont need to hold any lock etc.

If you wish to make it using `Arraylist`, you will have to make it atomic from both the sides. i.e. to access `list`, they should first hold the lock to object and the proceed. If someone else holds the lock, then wait.

```
synchonized(list){
  fillFromDb(list);
  downloadAndRepopulateList(list);
}


private void downloadAndRepopulateList(List list) {
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        synhronized(list){
         list.clear();
         }
        // Some other clode
    }
}
}
```

Comment: so the downloadAndRepopulateList() method is called inside a synchronized keyword and also has a synchronized keyword on his body?

Comment: Yes. The thread calling `synchornized(list)` holds the lock object. In this case your other thread. Hence it is necessory

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you also have to make synchronization on your `fillFromDb` method. So in the end you would have two synchronized parts, one that synchronizes your filling of the list and another synchronizes clear of the list. Also you can use your list as a mutex, but I would recommend you to have a separate object as mutex, it could me just like `Object mutex = new Object();`.